# Automatically inserting data into a table using a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, constraints

I would like to ask you a rather easy question but I cannot get my head around it as I am a beginner in SQL.

My task is: Enter initial data into BankStats2 by inserting rows into BankStats2 that
contain the branch names together with how many loans are in the Loan
table for that branch name.

```
desc BankStats2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 BRANCHNAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 NUMBEROFLOANS                                      NUMBER(38)
```

---

```
desc Loan
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMERNAME                                       CHAR(20)
 BRANCHNAME                                         CHAR(20)
 AMOUNT                                             NUMBER(38)
 LOANNUMBER                                NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

---

```
 select branchName,count(customerName) from Loan group by branchName;

BRANCHNAME           COUNT(CUSTOMERNAME)
-------------------- -------------------
Yorkshire                              3
RoyalBank                              1
Midlands                               3
```

Basically, I would like to insert this information in the BankStats2 table and the way I thought of doing it is by creating a procedure which I will show below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PopulateBankStats AS
CURSOR someLoanRows IS
SELECT branchName,COUNT(customerName) FROM loan GROUP BY branchName;
aBranchNameRow loan.branchName%TYPE;
numberOfLoans INT;
BEGIN
OPEN someLoanRows;
LOOP
FETCH someLoanRows INTO aBranchNameRow, numberOfLoans;
INSERT INTO BankStats2 VALUES (aBranchNameRow,numberOfLoans);
EXIT WHEN someLoanRows%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE someLoanRows;
END;
/
```

But executing it give me the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (N0757934.SYS_C0034405) violated
ORA-06512: at "N0757934.POPULATEBANKSTATS", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Not related to the error you're getting, but you should check `someLoanRows%NOTFOUND` **immediately** after the `fetch`, otherwise you will attempt to insert a record when the cursor is empty and that will also cause your procedure to hurl.

Answer (score 0):

This insert fails: `INSERT INTO BankStats2 VALUES (aBranchNameRow,numberOfLoans);` 
due to the error: `ORA-00001: unique constraint (N0757934.SYS_C0034405) violated`
This means that there is an unique constraint created on some of the columns of the table `BankStats2`.
In order to find which column has unique constraint, run this query:

```
select * from USER_IND_COLUMNS where index_name = 'SYS_C0034405';
```

Your procedure is trying to insert a record with a value of this column which already is existing in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the [INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) statement.

What your procedure is doing is **exactly this insert statement**:

```
INSERT INTO BankStats2 (BRANCHNAME,NUMBEROFLOANS)
SELECT branchName,COUNT(customerName) FROM loan GROUP BY branchName;
```

It is always preferable to use SQL statement (if possible) instead of the PL/SQL cursor loop logik - search [Tom Kyte's](https://asktom.oracle.com/) "row by row - slow by slow" for an explantion.

Even if you want to use a procedure at all cost - use this `INSERT` in the preocedure.

Your **exception** means that you try to insert a value of the column `BRANCHNAME` that already exists in the table `BankStats2`.

This could be by an accident or a systematic problem.

If it is an accident, simple clean the data, i.e. DELETE the row(s) with the corresponding keys from the `BankStats2` table.

This query returns the values existing in both tables

```
select BRANCHNAME from BankStats2 
intersect 
select branchName  FROM loan;
```

If you want to systematically avoid inserting the *duplicated* row, add this logik in your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO BankStats2 (BRANCHNAME,NUMBEROFLOANS)
SELECT branchName,COUNT(customerName) 
FROM loan
WHERE branchName IS NOT NULL 
and branchName NOT IN (select BRANCHNAME from BankStats2)
GROUP BY branchName;
```

Note that the SELECT excludes the row with the value that already exists in the target table - using `NOT IN (subquery)`.

Note also that I'm approaching your **next possible problem**. The column `BRANCHNAME` is non nullable in  `BankStats2`, but *is nullable* (i.e. may contain NULL) in `loan`, so you would fail to insert the row with NULL to the table `BankStats2`. Therefore I exclude those rows with the `branchName IS NOT NULL` predicate.

If you want to process the existing keys with an UPDATE logik, check the [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement.